# BeizerSQL library removed in processing?

Tags: database, sqlite, processing

I just started learning sqlite and wanted to use it in processing but when I try to download
the library it says 'version 0.2.2 not compatable'. Is it removed? I really want to use it. Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the library has not been updated to work with Processing 3. You can still use the library, you just have to use Processing 2.2.1, which you can still get from [the download page](https://processing.org/download/?processing).

It might be the case that the library still works but its meta data just hasn't been updated. If that's the case, you can still use the library with Processing 3 by installing it manually.